# How do I retrieve an item data by id and pass it to another component in React16 with Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to create an edit screen. I have a component called Task that looks like this

```
const Task = ({task}) => {
  return (
    <li>
      <div>
        <div>{task.text}</div>
        {task.day}
      </div> 
      <div className="icons">
        <Link 
          to={`/edit/${task.id}`} > 
          <RiEdit2FillIcon />
        </Link>
      </div>
    </li>
  )
}
```

That goes to a parent component with a tasks.map() and then to the main component that will render the list of tasks. But from this component, I want to click on that Edit Icon and open an Edit screen that is already Routed like this `<Route path='/edit/:id' component={EditTask}/>` That EditTask component is what I am working on now

```
import React from 'react'
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import Task from './components/Task'

const EditTask = () => {
  const api ="http://localhost:5000"

  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]) 
  const [task, setTask] = useState([]) 
  const [text, setText] = useState('')
  const [day, setDay] = useState('')
  const [reminder, setReminder] = useState(false)

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    updateData()
  }
  //Get Request
  useEffect(() => {
    const getTask = async () => {
      const tasksFromServer = await fetchTask()
      setTasks(tasksFromServer)
    }
    getTask()
  },[])

  const fetchTask = async (id) => {
    const res = await fetch(`${api}/tasks/${id}`)
    const data = await res.json()
    console.log(data)
    return data
  }

  //Update request
  const updateData = async (id) => {
    const taskToEdit = await fetchTask(id)
    const updateTask = {
      ...taskToEdit, 
      reminder: !taskToEdit.reminder,
      text: taskToEdit.text,
      day: taskToEdit.day
    }

    const res = await fetch(`${api}/tasks/${id}`, {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(updateTask)
    })
    const data = await res.json()

    setTasks(
      tasks.map((task) => 
        task.id === id 
        ? {
            ...task, 
            reminder: data.reminder,
            text: data.text,
            day: data.day
          } 
        : task
      )
    )
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <header className='header'>
        <h1>Edit</h1>
        <Link to="/" className="btn btn-primary">Go Back</Link>
      </header>
      <form className="add-form" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <Task task={task}/>
        <div className="form-control">
          <label>Task</label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Add Task" value={text} onChange={(e)=> setText(e.target.value)} />
        </div>
        <div className="form-control">
          <label>Day & Time</label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Add Day & Time"  value={day} onChange={(e)=> setDay(e.target.value)}/>
        </div>
        <div className="form-control form-control-check">
          <label>Set Reminder</label>
          <input type="checkbox" checked={reminder} value={reminder} onChange={(e)=> setReminder(e.currentTarget.checked)}/>
        </div>
        <input className="btn btn-block" type="submit" value="Save Task" />
      </form>
    </div>
    
  )
}

export default EditTask
```

I'm a bit lost here. I can't figure out how to pass the ID from Task.js to EditTask.js and populate the form with the data form that ID.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get id in `EditTask` with `useParams` in `"react-router`

```
import { useParams } from "react-router";

const EditTask = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
}
```